# IBM Worklight - Unable to connect to database when using IP address instead of localhost

Tags: mysql, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm currently creating a Worklight application that retrieves some data from my computer's MySQL database.

When I try to run the app, it cannot connect to the database. The error happens when I change the URL of the database to an IP address (192.168.6.1 (my computer's localhost)).

When I test it from my computer by invoking the worklight procedure (the address is localhost) it works fine, but when I change the URL to the IP address, it shows an error:

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0012E: ERROR: Could not connect to database. Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (null,  message from server: "Host 'stephen-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"). [project BarcodeScannerSample]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0012E: ERROR: Could not connect to database. Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (null,  message from server: "Host 'stephen-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"). [project BarcodeScannerSample]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0012E: ERROR: Could not connect to database. Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (null,  message from server: "Host 'stephen-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"). [project BarcodeScannerSample]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0012E: ERROR: Could not connect to database. Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.). [project BarcodeScannerSample]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0012E: ERROR: Could not connect to database. Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.). [project BarcodeScannerSample]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0020E: Ajax request exception: There is no application in the DB with the id 'BarcodeScannerSampleApp'. [project BarcodeScannerSample]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error description: INTERNAL_ERROR, error message: FWLSE0069E: An internal error occurred during gadget request  [project BarcodeScannerSample]There is no application in the DB with the id 'BarcodeScannerSampleApp'., User Identity {SubscribeServlet=null, wl_authenticityRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=null, SampleAppRealm=null, wl_antiXSRFRealm=null, wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, WorklightConsole=null, wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_anonymousUserRealm=null}. [project BarcodeScannerSample] 
                                                                                                               com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0012E: ERROR: Could not connect to database. Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (null,  message from server: "Host 'stephen-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"). [project BarcodeScannerSample]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0020E: Ajax request exception: There is no application in the DB with the id 'BarcodeScannerSampleApp'. [project BarcodeScannerSample]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error description: INTERNAL_ERROR, error message: FWLSE0069E: An internal error occurred during gadget request  [project BarcodeScannerSample]There is no application in the DB with the id 'BarcodeScannerSampleApp'., User Identity {SubscribeServlet=null, wl_authenticityRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=null, SampleAppRealm=null, wl_antiXSRFRealm=null, wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, WorklightConsole=null, wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_anonymousUserRealm=null}. [project BarcodeScannerSample] 
                                                                                                               com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0020E: Ajax request exception: There is no application in the DB with the id 'BarcodeScannerSampleApp'. [project BarcodeScannerSample]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error description: INTERNAL_ERROR, error message: FWLSE0069E: An internal error occurred during gadget request  [project BarcodeScannerSample]There is no application in the DB with the id 'BarcodeScannerSampleApp'., User Identity {SubscribeServlet=null, wl_authenticityRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=null, SampleAppRealm=null, wl_antiXSRFRealm=null, wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, WorklightConsole=null, wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_anonymousUserRealm=null}. [project BarcodeScannerSample] 
                                                                                                               com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0020E: Ajax request exception: There is no application in the DB with the id 'BarcodeScannerSampleApp'. [project BarcodeScannerSample]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error description: INTERNAL_ERROR, error message: FWLSE0069E: An internal error occurred during gadget request  [project BarcodeScannerSample]There is no application in the DB with the id 'BarcodeScannerSampleApp'., User Identity {SubscribeServlet=null, wl_authenticityRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=null, SampleAppRealm=null, wl_antiXSRFRealm=null, wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, WorklightConsole=null, wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_anonymousUserRealm=null}. [project BarcodeScannerSample] 
                                                                                                               com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0020E: Ajax request exception: There is no application in the DB with the id 'BarcodeScannerSampleApp'. [project BarcodeScannerSample]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error description: INTERNAL_ERROR, error message: FWLSE0069E: An internal error occurred during gadget request  [project BarcodeScannerSample]There is no application in the DB with the id 'BarcodeScannerSampleApp'., User Identity {SubscribeServlet=null, wl_authenticityRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=null, SampleAppRealm=null, wl_antiXSRFRealm=null, wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, WorklightConsole=null, wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_anonymousUserRealm=null}. [project BarcodeScannerSample] 
                                                                                                               com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
[WARNING ] FWLSE0082W: Failed to deploy adapter. This may be due to a JavaScript error in your adapter implementation (archive:  'C:\Users\stephen\AppData\Local\Temp\loginAdapter7158962596204999276.adapter'). [project mywatermelon]
The 'adapter' version '6.1.0.00.20131219-1900' is different than the version of Worklight Server '6.0.0'. 
Use Worklight Studio '6.0.0' to build and deploy the application.
[WARNING ] FWLSE0082W: Failed to deploy adapter. This may be due to a JavaScript error in your adapter implementation (archive:  'C:\Users\stephen\AppData\Local\Temp\myRESTAdapter36508485292314915.adapter'). [project mywatermelon]
The 'adapter' version '6.1.0.00.20131219-1900' is different than the version of Worklight Server '6.0.0'. 
Use Worklight Studio '6.0.0' to build and deploy the application.
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0012E: ERROR: Could not connect to database. Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (null,  message from server: "Host 'stephen-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"). [project BarcodeScannerSample]
```

Below is the adapter XML's connectivity settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
...
  <connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
      <!-- Example for using a JNDI data source, replace with actual data source name -->
      <!-- <dataSourceJNDIName>java:/data-source-jndi-name</dataSourceJNDIName> -->

      <!-- Example for using MySQL connector, do not forget to put the MySQL connector library in the project's lib folder -->
      <dataSourceDefinition>
        <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
        <url>jdbc:mysql://192.168.6.1:3306/barcode</url>
          <user>root</user>
          <password>170693</password> 
      </dataSourceDefinition>
    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="5" />
  </connectivity>
  ...
  ...
</wl:adapter>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which database front-end you're using, but you need to go to the user creation/permission screen and make sure you have given the user "root" permission to connect to both `localhost` and `%` (all), so that the IP address would be accepted as well.

For example: `root@%` rather than/in addition to `root@localhost`.

This is mentioned [in slide #14 of the SQL adapter training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_03_SQL_adapter_-_Communicating_with_SQL_database.pdf).

BTW, you could probably keep it as localhost instead of an IP address (as long as you're testing in your local network). It shouldn't matter for the device. Did you try?

Comment: sorry, but i don't know how to implement that. i'm using a jdbc connection to access mysql database, and I use phpmyadmin to manage the database

Comment: yes i've tried to test it using localhost as the IP address, but it doesn't work

Comment: Then you'll need to figure it out. Read the phpmyadmin documentation.

Comment: A quick google search brought this up. Run a google search. http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/user_management

Comment: great, it's finally working after i changed the privilege. thanks a lot!