# Connect Worklight App running on device with DB2 running on local computer

Tags: db2, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am working on **IBM Worklight** for the past few months.. Accordingly i have created my App which connects to **IBM DB2 Database for login/Registration** and other purposes. My problem is that if I **create an apk file** and install it on an Android device, **how do I connect with the DB2 database running on my local computer so that I can login successfully?** Will **Virtual Router** help me in this matter? If so **how?** Please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to this one: [IBM Worklight SQL adapter for real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558001/ibm-worklight-sql-adapter-for-real-device/23578915#23578915)

Make sure the host (your computer) and the device, both connect to the same network and that this network is able to access the public Internet.

Make sure that your DB2 server running on your host is able to accept all connections.

If you prefer to continue working locally (= same network but not open to public connections), make sure that you use an IP address for both the DB2 server and Worklight Server instead of "localhost". This tends to help).

Comment: I've connected my device with the computer where the server is running... But when I tried to test the connection by attempting to connect to the worklight server console from the device, I have been disappointed every time even though it showed that they were on the same network. I used the IP address of the worklight server instead of "localhost".. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using SQL adapter to access the DB for login. So to test in real device your device should be able to connect to your worklight server.

for that you can share your network in Wifi and connect your device to the same network and test.

you can test the connectivity by connecting to the worklight server console using your device browser.

Comment: Indeed I am using SQL Adapter.. and I've connected my device with the computer where the server is running... But when I tried to test the connection by attempting to connect to the worklight server console from the device, I have been disappointed every time even though it showed that they were on the same network. I used the IP address of the worklight server instead of "localhost".. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Are you connecting your server network via Wifi? or USB?

Comment: so you are sharing you network via wifi from your windows based PC. If it is open network just try to access any other hosted site. If you cant able to access any links mostly the problem is with the wifi sharing.